# Cohort analysis SQL code double counting units and sales

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Writing a SQL code for a cohort analysis. I got the buying patterns down but when I bring in units and sales amount, I notice my units and sales are getting doubled for customers who purchased more than one unit and I can't figure out why it's doing that. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Data and query result: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDmL4RHjSpC7DgpkcDmOxn0BWwrQVSdVeGpW0j1_7x8/edit?usp=sharing

```
    SELECT "T1"."amazon-order-id"
        ,"T1"."BRAND"
        ,"T1"."buyer-email"
        ,"T2"."purchase-date" "Cohort"
        ,"T1"."purchase-date"
        ,DATEDIFF(Day, "T2"."purchase-date", "T1"."purchase-date") AS "Days Difference"
        ,CASE 
            WHEN "Days Difference" = 0
                THEN 'NTB'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 15
                THEN '0-15 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 30
                THEN '15-30 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 45
                THEN '30-45 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 60
                THEN '45-60 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" < 90
                THEN '60-90 days'
            WHEN "Days Difference" > 90
                THEN '90+ days'
            END "Age"
        ,SUM("T1"."shipped-quantity") AS "Units Sold"
        ,SUM("T1"."item-price") AS "Sales"
FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T1
LEFT JOIN "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2 ON "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2"."buyer-email"
    AND "T2"."purchase-date" = (SELECT MIN("T2E"."purchase-date")
                                FROM "DATA_WAREHOUSE"."PUBLIC"."AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT" AS T2E
                                WHERE "T1"."buyer-email" = "T2E"."buyer-email" AND "T1"."purchase-date" >= "T2E"."purchase-date")
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
    ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,
    CASE WHEN "Age" = 'NTB' THEN 1
           WHEN "Age" = '0-15 days' THEN 2
           WHEN "Age" = '15-30 days' THEN 3
           WHEN "Age" = '30-45 days' THEN 4
           WHEN "Age" = '45-60 days' THEN 5
           WHEN "Age" = '60+ days' THEN 6
           ELSE 7 END
```

Comment: Can you make the sheet public.

Comment: your ORDER BY would give 100% the same answer as `ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,6`

Comment: @Pankaj it's public now. my bad

Answer (score 0):

So the simple answer is because you have more than one `AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT` one the same date as the min.

as this simple data shows:

```
WITH data_a(id, date, value) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date, 10),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date, 10)
), data_b(id, date) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date)
)
select a.id
    ,sum(a.value)
from data_a as a
join data_b as b
    on a.id = b.id and a.date = b.date
group by 1
order by 1;
```

| ID | SUM(A.VALUE) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 |

which is the same as:

```
select a.id
    ,sum(a.value)
from data_a as a
join data_b as b
    on a.id = b.id and a.date = (select min(c.date) from data_b as c where a.id = c.id and a.date >= c.date)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

which is the core of your problem.

but this can be show via this:

```
WITH data_a(id, date, value) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date, 10),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date, 10)
), data_b(id, date, b_id) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date, 1),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date, 2),
    (2, '2022-04-01'::date, 3)
)
select a.*, b.*
from data_a as a
join data_b as b
    on a.id = b.id and a.date = (select min(c.date) from data_b as c where a.id = c.id and a.date >= c.date)
```

| ID | DATE | VALUE | ID | DATE | B_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 10 | 1 | 2022-04-01 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 10 | 2 | 2022-04-01 | 2 |
| 2 | 2022-04-01 | 10 | 2 | 2022-04-01 | 3 |

### Comment Repsonce:

To be honest, you comment was crazy talk, I feel like it boils down to:

```
WITH data_a(id, date, value) as (
    select * from values
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date, 10),
    (1, '2022-04-01'::date, 10)
)
SELECT id, sum(value) as why_is_this_not_10
from data_a
group by 1;
```

`why_is_this_not_10` is because you have deduplicated your data. But you question was stated as "when there are many sales my number are double counted" and the answer is "because you are poorly joining your data and need to deduplicate it". So at this point responding with, "I cannot deduplicate it because there is duplicates in it" is circular madness.

The problem is:  `X = MIN(X)` can match for more than one row. If you only ever want one row, you need a method of picking just one winner, if ALL values in the row are equal, thus you have no extra column to select amongst as part of an ORDER BY, then you can pick any row, and this is exactly what ROW_NUMBER() will do for you. There will only ever be one row with the number 1.

Now to be fair to you, the original code did not show you how to solve the problem, just answer this part:

> I can't figure out why it's doing that

To solve it you need to

change to this:

```
SELECT t1."amazon-order-id"
    ,t1."BRAND"
    ,t1."buyer-email"
    ,min(t1."purchase-date") over (partition by t1."buyer-email") as "Cohort"
    ,t1."purchase-date"
    ,DATEDIFF(Day, "Cohort", t1."purchase-date") AS "Days Difference"
    ,CASE 
        WHEN "Days Difference" = 0 THEN 'NTB'
        WHEN "Days Difference" < 15 THEN '0-15 days'
        WHEN "Days Difference" < 30 THEN '15-30 days'
        WHEN "Days Difference" < 45 THEN '30-45 days'
        WHEN "Days Difference" < 60 THEN '45-60 days'
        WHEN "Days Difference" < 90 THEN '60-90 days'
        WHEN "Days Difference" > 90 THEN '90+ days'
    END "Age"
    ,SUM(t1."shipped-quantity") AS "Units Sold"
    ,SUM(t1."item-price") AS "Sales"
FROM DATA_WAREHOUSE.PUBLIC.AMAZON_FULFILLED_SHIPMENT_REPORT AS t1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
ORDER BY 2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Hi Simeon. This doesn't work because the order ID gets repeated if an order has more than one unit. (An order with 4 units sold will show up as 4 separate rows with same order ID, email, date, 1 unit, and cost of 1 unit) - I cannot NOT sum it up because it would overcount my PURCHASES